# steps to create single view item in android with json

Tags: android, json, android-layout, android-listview

I am new in android and want to view single item , I have created list of item from JSON successfully.

This is the adapter

```
public class ListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
Context context;
LayoutInflater inflater;
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;
ImageLoader imageLoader;
HashMap<String, String> resultp = new HashMap<String, String>();
public ListViewAdapter(Context context,
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arraylist) {
    this.context = context;
    data = arraylist;
    imageLoader = new ImageLoader(context);
}
public int getCount() {
    return data.size();
}
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    TextView country;
    ImageView flag;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_item, parent, false);
    resultp = data.get(position);
    country = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.country);
    flag = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.flag);
    country.setText(resultp.get(PhotosActivity.COUNTRY));
    imageLoader.DisplayImage(resultp.get(PhotosActivity.FLAG), flag);
    itemView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            resultp = data.get(position);
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, SingleItemView.class);
            intent.putExtra("country", resultp.get(PhotosActivity.COUNTRY));
            intent.putExtra("flag", resultp.get(PhotosActivity.FLAG));
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    return itemView;
}
}
```

Comment: In SingleItemView class, just get data that you are sending through Intent and show it?

Comment: I tried to show data but the app terminate , sorry this is the first app for me , please help

Comment: You need to post error log.